# No results from new component (Angular + ASP.NET Core)

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

help me please. I create an application based on the course - but the course is based on asp.net core 2 and angular 5. But I do everything in the current versions. There is a problem that I cannot solve.

I have a controller that returns a Quiz list from the Latest method in JSON format.

**QuizController.cs**

```
//GET api/quiz/latest
[HttpGet("Latest/{num?}")]
public IActionResult Latest(int num = 10)
{
  [other operations...]
  return new JsonResult(sampleQuizzes, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
}
```

Until then, everything works because by calling GET in postman the list is displayed.

Then I wanted to add the client part in Angular and display the list on the HOME page.

**ClientApp/src/app/quiz/quiz-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";   
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";   

@Component({
  selector: "quiz-list",                     
  templateUrl: './quiz-list.component.html',  
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-list.component.css']   
})

export class QuizListComponent {           
  title: string;
  selectedQuiz: Quiz;
  quizzes: Quiz[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.title = "Lists of latest quizzes";
    var url = baseUrl + "api/quiz/Latest";
    http.get<Quiz[]>(url).subscribe(result => {  
      this.quizzes = result;                    
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

  onSelect(quiz: Quiz) {                         
    this.selectedQuiz = quiz;
    console.log("You choose quiz id " + this.selectedQuiz.Id);
  }
}
```

**ClientApp/src/app/quiz/quiz-list.component.html**

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>      
<ul class="quizzes">
  <li *ngFor="let quiz of quizzes"
      [class.selected]="quiz === selectedQuiz" 
      (click)="onSelect(quiz)">          
    <span>{{quiz.Title}}</span>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

**ClientApp/src/app/app.module.ts**

```
[...]
import { QuizListComponent } from './quiz/quiz-list.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    QuizListComponent   
  ],
  imports: [

[...]
```

**After starting the application, only the title of the component from the html template is displayed on my website: "Lists of latest quizzes". Nothing more. Does anyone know where the bug is?**

Comment: Can you check if there are any errors in the console when you open the page? Also check for the network tab and see if the request really happened. I think it is generally recommended to use angulars `ngOnInit` hook to execute functions, instead of the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your console idea was very good. It turned out that the error was in the html tag. The LI tag in quiz-list.component.html had 3 lines and I placed a comment at the end of one line